# How to use the Hands-free profile on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, embedded

I want to be able to reject and accept calls on iPhone from another embedded device. I have nordic 8001 bluetooth chip. From what i read, i can see that iOS supports these Bluetooth profiles:

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3647

How can i use the Hands-free Profile? From what i read, i must send AT commands. How can I open a communication between the iOS and my embedded device to send these commands?

Do i need to join de Mfi program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Nordic 8001 only does Bluetooth Low Energy, and the Hands-Free Profile (HFP) doesn't work over BLE (only classic Bluetooth).

The only way to reject/accept calls on iOS is through HFP, so you'll need a different Bluetooth chip (one that supports classic Bluetooth)